# How to make MySQL field unique without creating B+Tree INDEX

Tags: mysql, indexing, varchar, unique-key

As I know, MySQL creates indexes automatically, if you trying to add unique_key to some field.

But what should I do, if I need to add, for example, unique_key for VARCHAR(256) field type.
Doing this in usually way, MySQL create an index by default.

Should take into account that MySQL works too bad with looooong VARCHAR indexes.
What should I do to create unique_key without index?

Comment: Why don't you want to create an index?

Comment: citation : Should take into account that MySQL works too bad with looooong VARCHAR indexes.

Comment: Does MySQL really consider a `varchar(256)` as a loooooong varchar value? I wasn't aware that it's that limited. Did you encounter any problems when you did create an index on that table?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set column to be unique without adding index.

But what if you add another column and will keep hash from your first column value there? (MD5 for example). And set it as UNIQUE?

Comment: But MD5 can't be unique, it may has the same value for different keys for some probability

Comment: Do you really need to worry about collisions in your case?

Comment: In this concrete case NO, but I encounter this problem is not the first time. I would like to know the answer to this question.